# Is it safe to uninstall nouveau driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 18.10, nouveau

I got a Dell laptop with intel/nVidiea GPU (GTX 1050i). The bios does not have mux.

It's a fresh install direct to 18.10, installed nVidia drivers directly from Ubuntu default repos. nVidia X Server settings is available and the laptop is happy always running on nVidia.

Like many others I see around the web gnome is always locking up a bit here or there and everything I read points back to the nouveau driver.

Let me be clear: I 100% do not care about the intel GPU or switching cards or anything. I just want to clean boot this always on the nVidia card and never look back.

From this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia it shows to uninstall/purge the nouveau driver. I tried to disable it on GRUB, but not much luck there. Tried via GRUB in case anything goes wrong it's easy to reboot back into it.

Given my lack of luck on disabling it, I'm planning to just go ahead and remove, BUT, considering it's my work PC and I already spend too much time on it instead of you know, actual work, the question is simple.

Is it safe to just type? `sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Csv00001028sd0000087Cbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

typing `lsmod | grep nouveau` gives me empty.

Comment: IIRC a proper installation (not to say you did it incorrectly, maybe this is just an issue with the ubuntu package) should completely blacklist the nouveau driver, so yes this should be fine!

Comment: Nnvidia's proprietary driver installation disable nouveau. What makes you think otherwise? lsmod clearly tells it's not loaded.

Comment: @mikewhatever because still shows on on the `devices` command and even thou I'm a Linux daily user, some (a lot) of its inner workings are plain magic to me. But it seems you're telling me that the driver package is installed but 100% sure it's not being used by the system. Which means, the actual issues I've been looking for does not come from the `nouveau` driver. Is that it?

Comment: As has now been stated twice, nouveau is blacklisted when the nvidia driver is installed. So yes

Comment: Ubuntu-drivers shows all available options for a device. Several drivers may be available, but it doesn't mean it all are in use, as is indicated by `lsmod` is this case. It is unlikely that nouveau has anything to do with your issues, and having `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` removed won't affect the system in any way.

Comment: Thanks to both j-money and mikewhatever if someone wants to write as answer and get a green tick mark, just write it.